# How can I move logo before sitetitle in Wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

How can I move the logo before the Site Title in WordPress?

I have this code so far:

```
function smartline_display_site_title() { ?>
    <div class='my-logo'>
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/AA.gif">
    </div>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" 
       title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"
       rel="home">
      <h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
    </a>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set or Add  `display: inline-block` to `.my-logo` and `.site-title`

```
.my-logo{
display: inline-block;
}

.site-title{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Based on your website you can move your image to the left

```
<img src="http://abraham-accountants.co.uk/wp-content/themes/smartline-lite/images/AA.gif" style="float: left;">
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/31st9zoc/)**

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Smartline Lite: header.php file and change the below given code.
Let me know if it works ....

```
        <div id="logo" class="clearfix">

            <?php do_action('smartline_site_title'); ?>
<img src="image location" alt="alt title" height="auto" width="auto">

            <?php // Display Tagline on header if activated
            if ( isset($theme_options['header_tagline']) and $theme_options['header_tagline'] == true ) : ?>            
                <h2 class="site-description"><?php echo bloginfo('description'); ?></h2>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>

        <div id="header-content" class="clearfix">
            <?php get_template_part('inc/header-content'); ?>
        </div>

    </header>
```